# Undefiend data when get from backend api in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

I countered an undefined data from when i get all product form backend
I using React for frontend
and redux toolkit for handle global state
and NodeJS + express JS for backend
and database monogodb on atlas cloud

backend:

```
router.get(
    "/get-all-products",
    catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const products = await Product.find();

            res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
                products,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler(error, 400));
        }
    })
);
```

reducer:

```
import { createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


const initialState = {
    isLoading: true,
};


export const productReducer = createReducer(initialState, {
    getAllProductsRequest: (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
    },
    getAllProductsSuccess: (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.allProducts = action.payload;
    },
    getAllProductsFailed: (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
    },
});
```

action:

```
export const getAllProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: "getAllProductsRequest",
        });

        const { data } = await axios.get(`${server}/product/get-all-products`);
        dispatch({
            type: "getAllProductsSuccess",
            payload: data.products,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: "getAllProductsFailed",
            payload: error.response.data.message,
        });
    }
};
```

Store:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { userReducer } from './reducers/user';
import { sellerReducer } from './reducers/seller';
import { productReducer } from './reducers/product';
import { eventReducer } from './reducers/event';

const Store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userReducer,
        seller: sellerReducer,
        products: productReducer,
        events: eventReducer,
    },
});
```

jsx page :

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/styles";
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

import ProductCard from "../components/Route/productCard/ProductCard";
import Header from "../components/layout/Header";
import Loader from "../components/layout/Loader";
import Footer from "../components/layout/Footer";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const ProductsPage = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const categoryData = searchParams.get("category");
  const { allProducts, isLoading } = useSelector((state) => state.products);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  


  useEffect(() => {
    if (categoryData === null) {
      const d = allProducts;
      setData(d);
      console.log(d);
    } else {
      const d =
        allProducts && allProducts.filter((i) => i.category === categoryData);
      setData(d);
    }
    //    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }, [allProducts]);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <Header activeHeading={3} />
          <br />
          <br />
          <div className={`${styles.section}`}>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-[20px] md:grid-cols-2 md:gap[25px] lg:grid-cols-4 lg:gap-[25px] xl:grid-cols-5 xl:gap-[30px] mb-12">
              {data &&
                data.map((i, index) => <ProductCard data={i} key={index} />)}
            </div>
            {data && data.length === 0 ? (
              <h1 className="text-center w-full  pb-[100px] text-[20px]">
                No Products Found !
              </h1>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductsPage;
```

Solution ------------

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllProducts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <Header activeHeading={3} />
          <br />
          <br />
          <div className={`${styles.section}`}>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-[20px] md:grid-cols-2 md:gap[25px] lg:grid-cols-4 lg:gap-[25px] xl:grid-cols-5 xl:gap-[30px] mb-12">
              {allProducts &&
                allProducts.map((i, index) => (
                  <ProductCard data={i} key={index} />
                ))}
            </div>
            {allProducts && allProducts.length === 0 ? (
              <h1 className="text-center w-full  pb-[100px] text-[20px]">
                No Products Found !
              </h1>
            ) : null}
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

i need to get raid of this error and know why it's happen

Comment: [`201 Created`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201) is definitely not the correct response type for a GET request. Also, what is the point of `success: true` in the response body? Doesn't the response status confer the same thing?

Comment: state.products in reduce store

Comment: What _exactly_ is the error (in full with stacktrace) and where do you see it? Also, how is your state initialised? What default value does `allProducts` have?

Comment: the products page keep loading and no data shows and when i console log the data i get undefined

Comment: When and where do you dispatch the `getAllProducts` action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [`201 Created`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201) is the wrong response status for your GET request. [`200 OK`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) would be much more appropriate and is already the default for `res.json()`.

   ```js
   res.json({ products });
   ```
2. `success: true` is totally unnecessary. If anything fails, your server will respond with an error response status (`4xx` / `5xx`)
3. What you're trying to do with the category filter is much more easily achieved using a [*memo* hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo)
4. You aren't checking for errors

```jsx
const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
const categoryData = searchParams.get("category");
const {
  allProducts,
  isLoading,
  error 
} = useSelector((state) => state.products);

const data = useMemo(
  () =>
    categoryData
      ? allProducts.filter(({ category }) => category === categoryData)
      : allProducts,
  [allProducts, categoryData]
);

if (error) {
  return <p className="warn">{error}</p>;
}
```

*Note:* there are no `useState` or `useEffect` hooks and most importantly **no `console.log()`**! If you want to debug, use [debugging tools](https://react.dev/learn/react-developer-tools).

Also ensure you define the initial state for `allProducts` as an array so you avoid any errors around `.map()` or `.filter()`.

```js
const initialState = {
  isLoading: true,
  allProducts: [], //  initial empty array
};
```

Comment: I changed the status to 200 instead of 201 and remove success: true
but error still 
and i try to setData(allProducts ) without filtering and no data showen

Comment: i map the data not the allProducts
which is in state and have initial value as an array

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76159884/edit) to show exactly how you define the initial state

Comment: I edit the jsx and reducer

Comment: @AhmedKhaled as expected, you were not defining an initial value for `allProducts`. I've updated my answer

Comment: i edit it put still not working :(

Comment: @AhmedKhaled what does your debugging tell you then? Use your browser's dev-tools to inspect the network requests and responses. Use the [React Dev Tools](https://react.dev/learn/react-developer-tools) to inspect your store; what values are being set into it?

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost:3000/products
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: and response show me html page

Comment: That doesn't align with the request your action is making. Are you sure you're even running the code in your question?

Comment: thank you alot i will add the solution now